# securing http transaction in browser games

Tags: security, encryption, flash, httprequest

I want to build a system where many people can play browser based simple (swf or html5) games (like snakes, car race, ludo etc). These games will be dead simple and does not require logic to be written in server.
The person who makes the highest score will win some prize.

Now the issue is securing the workflow. My approach may my incorrect, please feel free to suggest any alternative.
1. When game begins, a game id is generated.
2. When game ends, score and game id is sent back.

Problem is, Step 2 can be spoofed. Any one can send similar http request, with generated game id and any score. How do I know that score is coming from my game and its not being sent directly.

I thought of encrypting the score, but again the encryption mechanism will be there in javascript, which can easily be replicated.

Please help, thank in advance.

EDIT 1: I am not worried about sniffers, session hijacking, man in the middle attack. HTTPS will take care of all that. I am worried about user itself. He can just right click > inspect in a browser and check the request header being sent. He can easily replay same request header (just by right clicking and open in a new tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add layers of submission signing/encoding to obscure the data, and JS code obfuscation to make it harder for a user to undo that level of protection.

But ultimately you cannot solve the problem. You are placing the trust to run your code in the expected way to an untrusted client, and that naturally gives untrustable output. Spoofing the score is only one point of entry - an attacker could just as easily tamper with other parts of the client-side game logic to cheat.

Trusting the client is a perennial security problem to which there is little possible solution. For a trivial high score table that no-one cares about, you can potentially get away with a quantity of obfuscation to keep off the casual attacker, coupled with manual monitoring and pruning for obviously fraudulent submissions.

If you are considering offering actual desirable prizes, you may need to move some essential part of the game onto servers which you control. What pieces you need to protect and how is highly game-dependent and there are likely to be residual attacks that are difficult to defend against. (Consider for example the lengths that commercial multiplayer server-based games go to try to defend against client hacks like aimbots.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends upon the value of the data, but it sounds like the value is very low.

Pick a functionally impossible to guess ID. For example, a GUID (128 bit randomly generated value). If someone were to guess it, they get the game. But it's statistically impossible that they will ever get it right. And if you send it over HTTPS then they can't sniff it out (I'd send it over HTTPS, just because).

If you want to do better you can pick a random password to go with it, but I question if the math supports this as being necessary. It sounds like your data is crazy low value. Does it really matter?

FWIW, the bigger thing I'd be worried about is the person who decides to DoS you by asking you to store tons and tons of data for games that didn't exist...

Comment: I am not worried about sniffers, session hijacking or man in middle attack. I am worried about the user itself. Anyone can right click > inspect element > and check the request header (form data being sent) and replay the same request header (by right click and open in a new tab). This way instead of sending score=100 he can send score=1000.

Comment: HTTPS would mitigate sniffers & MITM. If the user gets to submit the score and you don't control the runtime, well that's just what it is. You need to get crisp about what threats worry you most. No matter what crypto you employ the user can manipulate their own state. You're only raising the bar a pinch by any sort of crazy scheme to obfuscate the data. You can do things to raise the bar, but it's just obfuscation given the assumptions being made thus far.